# Send constantly data from service to activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I'm getting data in a service, and this data is constantly updating.
I can see this data in Log, but I want to see it in an activity to display it. So what should I add to my service so that my activity would be instantly notified with updated data?

I can see and get data in the service when the task is completed, with the `onTaskCompleted` method, and this how I'm using it in my service.

(PS: I can send data from activity to service).

**EDIT**
I added some code to resolve the problem, but I have an error in the "SEND_DATA_INTENT": `SEND_DATA_INTENT cannot be resolved to a variable`

```
public class DownloadService extends Service  implements OnTaskCompleted {.....
     @Override
            public void onTaskCompleted(String result){

        results.add(result);//Ici on ajoute a chaque appel du service le debit 
        Intent intent = new Intent(SEND_DATA_INTENT);//i have an error here :SEND_DATA_INTENT cannot be resolved to a variable
        intent.putExtra("type", "message");
        sendBroadcast(intent);

    }
//i would like to send data to the activty here ,because i'm sure that the task is end, and i have the data that i need.
            }
}
```

In the main Activity i add  DataReciver  class

```
private class DataReciver extends BroadcastReceiver
            {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
                {
                    if (intent.getAction().equals(DownloadService.SEND_DATA_INTENT)) //i have an error here :SEND_DATA_INTENT cannot be resolved to a variable
                    {
                        Bundle bdl = intent.getExtras();
                        String type = bdl.getString("type");

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: There are several ways to do it. You can use Binders or BroadcastMessages. To make better realization post how you send data from activity to service.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but as i said i can send data from activity to service , BUT what i want is to send data from SERVICE to ACTIVITY @Demand

Comment: @Demand can you take loc please, to my edit.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add Broadcast reciever in the service and catch the data into broadcast reciever after that through a reciever event from this service with particular action and catch the action to the activity which you want to get it send the data through intent.

Comment: Thank you for replying .ok i'll try to do it.I'll post my result.